# How to create an element show and hide using localStorage with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to Javascript and I would like to create the following for example:

[image]

Basically, I am trying to get a custom content that can be closed by the user when needed. I heard that this can be done using localStorage with a timeout period.

Once the user clicks the close button, it stays hidden in the DOM until the timer expires, say 2-3 days and then re-appear again in the page.

How do I go about doing it?

Would appreciate some help on this.

Thanks

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage for that.
easier approach would be to use a cookie, on a cookie you can set the expiration time and it will be deleted automatically.

Using localStorage it will look something like this:

```
// User has clicked in the past
if (localStorage.userClickExpiration) {
    if (Date.now() > parseInt(localStorage.userClickExpiration)) {
        // Time expired, reset the localStorage and show the element
        localStorage.removeItem('userClickExpiration');
        $('.element').show();
    } else {
        $('.element').hide();
    }
}

// User click handler
function handleClick() {
    // Store the time when the auto hide will be expired, now + 2 days in milliseconds
    localStorage.userClickExpiration = Date.now() + (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    // Hide the element using jQuery
    $('.element').hide();
}
```